# How to calculate a running total of a value which is depending on the running total itself in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate a value and a running total of a value which are depending on the running total itself. The running total has to sum up the last four values, as long as the running total is less or equal than 3. If the running total is higher than 3, then the 4th value to add must be reduced by [running_total - 3]. 
If a value had to be reduced, then the subsequent running totals must consider the reduced value instead of the original value.

Any ideas on how to solve this in Oracle SQL?

**Example**

Given the following data:

```
create table val_table (id number, val number);

insert into val_table values (1, 0); 
insert into val_table values (2, 2); 
insert into val_table values (3, 0); 
insert into val_table values (4, 0); 
insert into val_table values (5, 2); 
insert into val_table values (6, 0); 
insert into val_table values (7, 3); 
insert into val_table values (8, 0); 
insert into val_table values (9, 3); 
insert into val_table values (10,0); 
commit;
```

The plain running total

```
select id
      ,val
      ,sum(val) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) as running_total
from val_table
);
```

outputs

```
============================
| ID | VAL | RUNNING_TOTAL |
|--------------------------|
| 1  |  0  |    0          |
| 2  |  2  |    2          |
| 3  |  0  |    2          |
| 4  |  0  |    2          |
| 5  |  2  |    4          |
| 6  |  0  |    2          |
| 7  |  3  |    5          |
| 8  |  0  |    5          |
| 9  |  3  |    6          |
| 10 |  0  |    6          |
============================
```

The required adjusted values and adjusted running totals are

```
====================================================
| ID | VAL | VAL_ADJUSTED | RUNNING_TOTAL_ADJUSTED |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1  |  0  |      0       |            0           |
| 2  |  2  |      2       |            2           |
| 3  |  0  |      0       |            2           |
| 4  |  0  |      0       |            2           |
| 5  |  2  |      1       |            3           |
| 6  |  0  |      0       |            1           | 
| 7  |  3  |      2       |            3           |
| 8  |  0  |      0       |            3           |
| 9  |  3  |      1       |            3           | 
| 10 |  0  |      0       |            3           | 
====================================================
```

Note that the adjusted value of ID=7 results in 2. The adjusted running total at ID=7 would be 0+1+0+3=4, which is greater than 3. Therefore, the value of ID=7 must be reduced by 1, resulting in the adjusted value of 2.

**Example 2**

Given the following data:

```
create table val_table2 (id number, val number);

insert into val_table2 values (1, 2); 
insert into val_table2 values (2, 2); 
insert into val_table2 values (3, 2); 
insert into val_table2 values (4, 2); 
insert into val_table2 values (5, 2); 
commit;
```

The required adjusted values and adjusted running totals are

```
====================================================
| ID | VAL | VAL_ADJUSTED | RUNNING_TOTAL_ADJUSTED |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1  |  2  |      2       |            2           |
| 2  |  2  |      1       |            3           |
| 3  |  2  |      0       |            3           |
| 4  |  2  |      0       |            3           |
| 5  |  2  |      2       |            3           |
====================================================
```

Comment: How did the value of ID 7 get adjusted to 2?

Comment: Running total at `ID=7` is `0+2+0+3 = 5` which is greater than 3 so the 7th adusted value should be "cut" by (which I assume means reduced by) the `running total - 3` which would give a value of `1` (not `2`). Or is there something wrong with how we are interpreting your question?

Comment: I understand that doing the roll up of the 4 proceedings, we take the adjusted values, which means that to get adjusted value a row x you have to know the adjusted value of its 3 precedings

Comment: The value of ID=7 got adjusted to 2 since the value of ID=5 got adjusted to 1. The adjusted running total at ID=7 would be 0+1+0+3=4, which is greater than 3. Therefore, the value of ID=7 must be reduced by 1, resulting in the adjusted value of 2.
So if a value had to be reduced, then the subsequent running totals must consider the reduced value instead of the original value.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this (but I can't quite work out how you got your adjusted values):

```sql
SELECT id,
       val,
       val_adjusted,
              SUM( val_adjusted ) OVER (
         ORDER BY id
         ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS running_total_adjusted
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         val,
         GREATEST(
           CASE
           WHEN running_total > 3
           THEN val - (running_total - 3)
           ELSE val
           END,
           0
         ) AS val_adjusted
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           val,
           SUM(val) OVER (
             ORDER BY id
             ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
           ) AS running_total
    FROM   val_table
  )
);
```

which outputs:

> ```
> ID | VAL | VAL_ADJUSTED | RUNNING_TOTAL_ADJUSTED
> -: | --: | -----------: | ---------------------:
>  1 |   0 |            0 |                      0
>  2 |   2 |            2 |                      2
>  3 |   0 |            0 |                      2
>  4 |   0 |            0 |                      2
>  5 |   2 |            1 |                      3
>  6 |   0 |            0 |                      1
>  7 |   3 |            1 |                      2
>  8 |   0 |            0 |                      2
>  9 |   3 |            0 |                      1
> 10 |   0 |            0 |                      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2dac2f365c1b68fa9e6c35d838e866f2)*

Comment: Thanks for the proposal.
The adjusted value seems to be adjusted with respect to the running total. In my case, the adjusted value must be adjusted with respect to the *adjusted* runnning total, resulting in an adjusted value of 2 for ID=7. 
I tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi is my understanding:

When doing the roll up of the 4 proceedings, we take the adjusted values, which means that to get adjusted value a row x you have to know the adjusted value of its 3 preceding.
This is the code I scripted for that:

**cte1** gets the adjustment value telling us by how much is row x off of 3 if we add the 3 preceding to its value

**cte2** just forces the adjustment value to 0 for row with value 0

**ct3** uses the adjustment factor with the val and those of the 3 preceeding to compute the val_adjusted
Final query builds the final windows function based on VAL_ADJUSTED

```
; with cte as
(
select id
      ,val
      ,case when sum(val) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) > 3 then 3 else sum(val) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) end as running_total
      ,case when 3 - sum(val) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) >= 0 then val else 3 - sum(val) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) end as adjustmentfactor
from val_table
),
cte2 as
(
select 
 id, val,
 case when val = 0 then 0 else abs(adjustmentfactor) end as adjustmentfactor
from cte
),
cte3 as
(
select 
 id, val, abs(adjustmentfactor) as adjustmentfactor ,
  case when val = 0 then 0 else
       case when 3 - sum(adjustmentfactor) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) < 0 then 
            val - (sum(adjustmentfactor) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) - 3)
       else
            adjustmentfactor
       end 
 end as VAL_ADJUSTED 
from cte2
)
select id, val, VAL_ADJUSTED,
sum(VAL_ADJUSTED) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) as RUNNING_TOTAL_ADJUSTED 
from cte3
;
```

The Output is:

```
id  val    VAL_ADJUSTED RUNNING_TOTAL_ADJUSTED
1   0              0        0
2   2              2        2
3   0              0        2
4   0              0        2
5   2              1        3
6   0              0        1
7   3              2        3
8   0              0        3
9   3              1        3
10  0              0        3
```

Comment: Is there any reason you calculate running_total in cte? It’s not used anywhere.

I added a second example data set to the question with which your query does not result the correct adjusted values.